# Modifying deprecated sizeWithFont method to boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was struggling with the problem of setting `UITextView` height that depends on its content.

Finally I find a solution that works pretty well but it warns me that method `sizeWithFont` that is used here is deprecated.

When I tried to modify the old method to new I got a "yellow" warning and I want to modify it to new `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` method.

There is my code I want to modify:

```
-(void)configureTextView {

    CGSize textViewSize = [self.descriptionStringShort sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:20]
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

    CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textViewSize.height;
    self.myTextView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you tried with `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` and exactly what the warning was.

Comment: It wasn't the warning but x and y of frame was setter to incorrect, it actually was shown somewhere else on screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt"
                                                                                        size:20]
                                                                 forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize textViewSize = [self.descriptionStringShort boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                                    options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                 attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;

    CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textViewSize.height;
    self.myTextView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CGSize textViewSize = [self.descriptionStringShort sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(210.0f, 2000.0f)];
```